# Generate nested subsets in dredge

Tags: r, mumin

In dredge (MuMIn package) I want to use "subset" in order to exclude any model combining variable A with one of B,C or D. I tried

`library(MuMIn)
 dg <- dredge (global.model, subset = !("A"&c("B","C","D"))`

which delivers the same result as 
`dg <- dredge (global.model, subset = !("A"&"B")`, thus only excludes models containing A and B together. Is there any way to feed subset with a vector of variable names?

I could use `subset=!(A&B)|!(A&C)|!(A&D)`, of course - however I'd prefer to use an "exclude-vector".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest expression for that is probably
`subset = !A | !sum(B, C, D)`. It has the same result as  `!A | !(B | C | D)`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed to `subset = !(A & sum(B,C,D))` and it worked.
Your code excludes the variables completely from analysis. Perhaps you can update your answer?
As a topping: can I add a second subset like `!B&C`?

Comment: I think, I found a way: `subset  =  !(A&sum(B, C, D)) && !(B&C))`
Just to understand it right: does this mean
- exclude models containing A and at least one of B, C, D
and
- exclude models containing both B,C together?

Comment: `!(A & sum(B,C,D))` is effectively identical to my example (not x or not y == not (x and y)). In addition you can use `sum(B, C, D) < N)` to limit the number of concurrent variables, or `> N` to set minimum number of variables. The `*nvar*` special variable is also useful for this purpose.